# Input only string or date type. I have an example for numerics, but it doesnt work for date / text

Tags: excel, vba

My column must accept only a single type of data. I've tried changing "IsNumeric" to "IsDate" or "IsText", but it doesnt work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$B$2:$B$4000" 'change range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
       If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
          MsgBox "XXXX", vbCritical, "ABACAXI"
          Target.Value = vbNullString
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `If Not IsDate(Target.Value) then …` OR …  `If Not VarType(Target.Value) = vbString then …`

Comment: It continues accepting all types of data :/

Comment: @VinicioLima Can you give us an example of some entries that are sneaking through?

Comment: @dwirony The example given works like a charm. It accepts only numbers and if the user type "a" at the cell, it returns an error. I need another code for receiving text / date type. For example: if it is a text, it must return an error for numbers. If it is a number/text (date example), it must return an error as well, because the input  wasn't the expected data.

Comment: Input in a cell is by default a string. To check if a number has been entered because you don't want a number as input, just do the opposite of your original check: `If IsNumeric(Target) then …`,As for dates, IsDate works well … but the input may not be in the format you would like, just use the `Format` function after …..

Comment: @Guest `Range.Value` is a `Variant`, not a `String`. The default is `Variant/Empty`, which is why `IsEmpty` returns `True` for a blank cell (but not for an empty string). OP: `If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value)` will be `True` when the cell's value is a `Variant/Error`, and that will throw a *type mismatch* error if you later try to read that value into anything other than a `Variant`, or otherwise coerce it to a non-variant data type, e.g. `If Target.Value <> vbNullString`, or `If Target.Value > 0`

Comment: @Mathieu: thanks for the  precision (it explains some behaviors I experienced in the past). I will use the following in the future .. `If IsNumeric(CStr(Target.Value)) then .. `, and `Target.Value = Trim(CStr(Target.Value))` if True...

Comment: @Guest `CStr` will fail given a `Variant/Error` - you want to pass the plain unaltered `Variant` to `IsNumeric`

Comment: @Mathieu: Interesting behavior and very interesting to know although I do not recall seeing failure on IsNumeric but I am sure it is bound to happen to me one day or another. Would `If Not IsError(IsNumeric(Target.Value)) then .. ` work?

Comment: The failure isn't `IsNumeric`, the failure is `CStr` trying to coerce a `Variant/Error` into a `String` - conversions from `Error` to `String` (or to anything else), whether implicit or explicit, will always throw a type mismatch error: say you have `value` assigned to `CVErr(xlErrNA)`; `IsNumeric(value)` will be `False`, but if you do `CStr(value)` you get a type mismatch - the implicit conversion blows up before `IsNumeric` even gets to see what parameters it's given. And `IsNumeric` yields a `Boolean`, `IsError(True)` will always be `False`.

Comment: @Mathieu: I understand better now .. thanks for your patience.